# Can ASCX or ASP.net files be saved as HTML files

Tags: asp.net, html, ascx

Can ASCX or ASP.net files be saved as HTML files?  if so, how?

Comment: For what purpose?...   From your browser you can save the output html, but what is that going to do for you?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Do you have HTML markup in the ASCX file which you need to extract into a static HTML page?  Are you trying to save the rendered output from dynamic content in an ASCX file?

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible, to get the rendered content of a User Control, do the following :

```
StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
Page pageHolder = new Page();
UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl("path to ascx file");
pageHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, true);
string htmlOutput = output.ToString();
```

Am sure you can adapt the above for ASPX page if required :-)

From there, saving that to a file should be fairly straight forward.

HTH.
D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly with the `Render` method of a `Page` or `UserControl`. Since the method is protected, you will need to create a control that subclasses either. From there, you've got access to do whatever you need.

e.g.

```
public partial class MyPage: Page
{
    public string GetPageContents()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        using (HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
              Render(writer);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

You probably wouldn't want to call this anytime before the `PreRenderComplete` event of the page though, since otherwise you can't be sure all child controls/events/etc have finished.